# Bad Request (400) on $.ajax post request flask

Tags: ajax, forms, post, flask, httprequest

For my webapplication in Flask I need to send two post requests in one submit:

The first one is to send my form data, here everything works fine.

But there's one field which can't be send via form (Tag-Field). So I wanted to get the tags of this field via javascript and then send it to my view with $.ajax post request.
Every time I click the submit button I get a Bad Request (400) error for the $.ajax post request. 
The other post request works fine.

Here's my javascript:

```
script language="javascript">
    function getTagList() {
        var tagArray = new Array();
        tagArray = $('#my-tag-list5').tags().getTags();
        var tags = tagArray.toString();
        console.log(tags);
        request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/dozent/fragenEingeben",
            data: JSON.stringify(tags),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.tags);
            },
        });
    }
</script>
```

The button which is calling the script AND the form submit looks like:

```
<li class="next"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success next btnPager btnPagerRight" name="createAndActivate" value="createAndActivate" onclick="getTagList();">Speichern</br><i>~ und freigeben ~</i></button></li>
```

When I print request.form in Flask I get this in my Python Console:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([])
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jan/2015 15:25:09] "POST /dozent/fragenEingeben HTTP/1.1" 400 -
ImmutableMultiDict([('createAndActivate', u'createAndActivate'), ('option2[]', u'answer1'), ('option2[]', u'answer2'), ('option2[]', u'answer3'), ('option2[]', u''), ('option[]', u'answer'), ('option[]', u''), ('question', u'Question'), ('time', u'10s')])
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jan/2015 15:25:10] "POST /dozent/fragenEingeben HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

And this is the error in my webbrowser:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/dozent/fragenEingeben 400 (BAD REQUEST)      jquery.min.js:4
  send                                                                  jquery.min.js:4 
  m.extend.ajax                                                         jquery.min.js:4
  getTagList                                                            fragenEingeben:240
  onclick                                                               fragenEingeben:227
```

This is my flask view:

```
#create question
@app.route('/dozent/fragenEingeben', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def fragenEingeben():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.form
        #If button "Speichern und freigeben" was clicked do the following
        if request.form['createAndActivate'] == 'createAndActivate':
            tags = request.json['tags']
            #Get ID of signed in lecturer
            lecturer = getLecturerID((session['email'],))
            #Write all in db
            createAndActivateQuestion(request.form['question'],"tag",lecturer,request.form['time'],request.form.getlist('option[]'),request.form.getlist('option2[]'))
            flash('Frage erfolgreich erstellt und aktiviert.')
            return jsonify(tags=tags)
        #If button "Speichern und nicht freigeben" was clicked do the following
        elif request.form['createQuestion'] == 'createQuestion':
            #Get ID of signed in lecturer
            lecturer = getLecturerID((session['email'],))
            #Write all in db
            createQuestion(request.form['question'],"tag",lecturer,request.form['time'],request.form.getlist('option[]'),request.form.getlist('option2[]'))
            flash('Frage erfolgreich erstellt.')
            return redirect(url_for('fragenEingeben'))
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('statistik'))
    else:
        pass
    return render_template('dozent/fragenEingeben.html')
```

When I want to get the data in the view, I get the following Error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Can anyone explain why I get a bad request for the first post request?

Comment: You'll need to show us your **Flask view** for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX request is executed *separately*, and *before the form is POSTed*. When the AJAX calls is sent, you cannot use `request.form` as that data has not been sent yet. It is instead being sent in a separate request following the AJAX request.

If you want to include the tags is your form POST, stick them in a `<input type="hidden">` field instead of using AJAX. AJAX is for out-of-band requests, not for adding data to an existing form POST.

So, instead of using `$.ajax` add the extra form field to your form:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="tag_list" id="tag_list" value="" />
```

and in your submit event handler update that field:

```js
tagArray = $('#my-tag-list5').tags().getTags();
$('#tag_list').val(JSON.stringify(tagArray));
```

and extract those tags in your Flask view:

```
import json

tags = json.loads(request.form['tag_list']))
```

Comment: but what's with my form data? How can I access them instead?

Comment: @JessicaBleile: sorry, I rewrote my answer once I realised that you are trying to augment a form POST.